# Are there circuits that operate on plaintext, analogous to how FHE works?

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption, circuit

Fully Homomorphic Encryption lets us operate over encrypted data. Is there something analogous that let us operate over plaintexts directly, without knowing the circuit?

For example, let's say that I store AES of the user's password, and I want to be able to change the user's password to `password +1` at my will without interacting with him. The user would be able to send me a circuit that decrypts the AES, adds +1 to the password, and re-encrypts it. The difference from FHE here is that I would be able to see the result `AES(password+1)` in plaintext, where in FHE I'd have the `FHE(AES(password+1))`

Comment: This talks about circuits [Representing a function as FHE circuit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63781/18298). No, you can design an FHE protocol that, you will have still the AES encrypted password+1. It is quite costly, though. With a true FHE that has semantical security, you can execute almost all circuits with some huge cotst.

Comment: In your case, why does the user has the AES key of the password?

Comment: And  [Can we proxy-re-encrypt using homomorphic encryption schemes?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9516/18298)

Comment: Not sure if I totally understand your answer but maybe you want to check out the malleability property, however malleable ciphers aren't semantically secure.

Comment: Obfuscation allows someone to run an unkown circuit on a known input and get the answer in clear. You can search for indistinguishability obfuscation, for example.